# Const methods and custom iterators

Tags: c++, oop, templates, iterator

I have a class that contains a `std::vector`, and another that is a custom `iterator` for that class.  It works great for non-const methods, but when I try to create an `iterator` in a `const` method, the compiler fails because it can't convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`.  For example, the code below fails, but if the call to `ConstFunc` is commented out, it compiles and runs fine.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class FooIter {
public:
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;

    FooIter(std::vector<T> &vec) {iterator = vec.begin();}
};

template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
    std::vector<T> vec;

    Foo() {}
    void NonConstFunc() {
        FooIter<T> iter(vec);
    }
    void ConstFunc() const {
        FooIter<T> iter(vec);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.NonConstFunc();
    foo.ConstFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to modify `FooIter` so it can serve as both `iterator` and `const_iterator`?

EDIT: A commenter asked "How do you plan to use `FooIter<T>` in a `const` method?"  Below is one example.

```
    std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> > find() const {
        std::vector< std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> > list(0);
        Matrix2dIterator<T> it = this->begin(true);
        Matrix2dIterator<T> itEnd = this->end(true);
        for (; it != itEnd; ++it) {
            if (*it) {
                list.push_back(std::make_pair(it.getRow(), it.getCol()));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

`Matrix2d` is "Foo", and `Matrix2dIterator` is "FooIter".  `find` needs to iterate over the `std::vector` which holds the matrix data, but it is not changing that data.

Comment: You may need a `FooIter` and a `ConstFooIter`, since `iterator` and `const_iterator` are different types. You _could_ do weird things with `union`/`variant`, but it would make your code difficult to read.

Comment: In my experience, trying to make the `iterator` and `const_iterator` type the same never works out.

Comment: How do you plan to use `FooIter<T>` in a `const` method?

Comment: You could try using some additional template parametrization of `FooIter` class but typically it's easier to just have two seperate types for iterator and const_iterator.

Comment: @rustyx I have added an example of how I intend to use the const_iterator to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is, that you could modify `vec` and therefore your class through a `std::vector<T>::iterator`. So you cannot have them in a `const` member function. The more technical reason is that in a `const` member function all members are `const` and the `std::vector` has the functions

```
std::vector<T>::iterator begin();
std::vector<T>::const_iterator begin() const;
std::vector<T>::const_iterator cbegin() const;
```

so if `vec` is `const` `begin()` will return a `const` iterator which is also very sensible, since you cannot modify the vector through a `const_iterator`.

You can adapt your code by providing a `ConstFooIter` that has a member of type `std::vector<T>::const_iterator` this would look like the following:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class ConstFooIter {
public:
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iterator;

    ConstFooIter(const std::vector<T> &vec) {iterator = vec.cbegin();}
};
```

Alternatively, you don't template on the value_type of the vector but on the vector itself, this detects `const`-ness automatically:

```cpp
#include <vector>
template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::vector<typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type>>>>
class FooIter {
public:
    decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()) iterator;

    FooIter(T &vec) {iterator = vec.begin();}
};

template <class T>
class Foo {
public:
    std::vector<T> vec;

    Foo() {}
    void NonConstFunc() {
        FooIter iter(vec);
    }
    void ConstFunc() const {
        FooIter iter(vec);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.NonConstFunc();
    foo.ConstFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this does not imply that you only have one class left. The `iter`s in your two methods will be of different types (`FooIter<std::vector<T>>` vs `FooIter<const std::vector<T>>`). The advantage is that the compiler will do the dirty work of writing the two classes for you and hence you decrease the code duplication since the two classes are nearly the same.

This comes at a disadvantage. It is not that easy to see which variant is used right now and using a `const` iterator in a non-`const` context (which you should always do if you do not intend to modify anything) is a bit tricky since `FooIter(vec)` will always return the non-`const` variant when `vec` is not const.

**EDIT:** Added some template magic to only allow `std::vector`, i.e. `std::set<int> s; FooIter f{s};` won't compile anymore.

Comment: Man, I had no idea how little I knew about templates.  I wasn't even aware that std::enable_if_t and the like existed.  Thanks for enlightening me and putting this together.

Comment: In the ```FooIter iter(vec);``` lines, what template specialization should I use for FooIter?  I know it should be something along the lines of ```FooIter<T, ???> iter(vec);```, but I don't know what to replace the question marks with.

Comment: Just use `FooIter<std::vector<T>>` or `FooIter<const std::vector<T>>`. The second parameter has a default value and does not have to (and actually should never) be provided.

Comment: @JimClay Template meta programming is a fun rabbit hole in C++.^^

Answer (score 0):

You should go for one of n314159's solutions. I'm just showing what the problem is of making your `FooIter` work for both non-const and const vectors.

You can add an overloaded constructor to `FooIter` that takes a const reference:

```
FooIter(const std::vector<T> &vec) {iterator = vec.begin();}
```

This would be enough, if it were not for the fact that `iterator` itself is non-const, and so the compiler will rightfully complain about that. You could have two member variables, one non-const and the other const:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;

FooIter(std::vector<T> &vec) {iterator = vec.begin();}
FooIter(const std::vector<T> &vec) {const_iterator = vec.begin();}
```

But then other member functions would need to know which one to use. You could add a flag variable for that, but that would be rather inefficient; it needs more memory (apart from the duplication of the iterator itself), and it needs a check for every member function call. So the best solution is to have two separate iterator classes, one for non-const and the other for const.

Answer (score 0):

maybe..?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


    template <class T>
    class FooIter {
    public:
        const typename vector<T>::iterator itr;         // const added

        FooIter(vector<T> &vec) : itr{vec.begin()} {}
    };

    template <class T>
    class Foo {
    public:
        vector<T> vec;

        Foo() {}
        void NonConstFunc() {
                FooIter<T> iter(vec);
        }
        void ConstFunc()  {                 // const removed, if
                FooIter<T> iter(vec);       // needed prefix it on each needed line
        }
    };

    int main()  {
        Foo<int> foo;
        foo.NonConstFunc();
        foo.ConstFunc();
        return 0;
    }
```